# Create multiple databases in ONgDB enterprise

Tags: database, graph, ongdb

Does ONgDB enterprise version support multiple databases? If so how can we create a new database.

I ran the following script

CREATE DATABASE testDB;

Got the error:

```
Invalid input 't': expected whitespace, comment, '=', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a relationship pattern, ',', LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 17 (offset: 16))
"CREATE DATABASE testDB"
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple databases are not supported in version 1.0 as it's a fork of neo4j before neo4j supported multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the original committers of ONgDB and am a committer for DozerDB.
Until ONgDB gets multi-database in place in the 2.0 version, you can check out DozerDB - which is a bootstrapping plugin that adds multi-database, enterprise constraints, and much more in 2024 to Neo4j Community Edition version 4 and 5.    https://dozerdb.org   https://github.com/dozerdb/